# Pairings algorithm challenge

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Say we have N males and N females.

For each [M_i, F_j] pair is an associated cost, say between 0.0 and 1.0.

Let's define a total pairing to be where every M is paired up with some F.

There are N! possible total pairings.

How to determine the total pairing with the least total cost?

Obviously for big N (say > 100) it is impractical to try to try brute force.

And is it possible to place bounds on O(n)?

If the condition is relaxed so that the challenge becomes to find a good candidate total pairing (rather than THE BEST), what effect does this have on the choice of algorithm?

Comment: The problem is a linear programming assignment problem. It can be solved in ~ O(N^3) time using the Hungarian Algorithm. I am not aware of any algorithm that runs in O(n) time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: This editorial can help you http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=hungarianAlgorithm